# Optimising Google Speed Insights API Script in Google Sheets

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pagespeed-insights

I have created a script in Google Apps Scripts and Google Sheets that returns some speed metrics from the urls that are pasted in the sheet.

The script works good, the only problem is that it takes forever to present the results in the sheet. It makes a call for each url, I suspect that's why it's slow.

Is there any way I can optimise this script so it gives me the results faster?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfGEI.png)

The code:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const API_STRING = sheet.getSheetByName("instructions").getRange("K10").getValues();
const PLATFORM = sheet.getSheetByName("urls").getRange("B1").getValues();
const OUTPUT_CELL = sheet.getSheetByName("urls").getRange("B5:" + ("K" + sheet.getLastRow()));
console.log(PLATFORM);

// KPI 
const lighthouseMetrics = [
  "first-contentful-paint",
  "largest-contentful-paint",
  'interactive',
  "cumulative-layout-shift",
  "speed-index",
  "total-blocking-time"
]
const fieldData = [
  "FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS",
  "LARGEST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS",
  "FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS",
  "CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT_SCORE"
]

// CALLING FUNCTION
async function fetch_array() {
  let URLS_LIST = sheet.getSheetByName("urls").getRange("A5:" + ("A" + sheet.getLastRow())).getValues();
  console.log(URLS_LIST)
  let arrayData = [];
  for (let element of URLS_LIST) {
    let dataEl = await getPageSpeedInfo(PLATFORM, element);
    let dataRow = produceArray(dataEl);
    arrayData.push(dataRow);
  }
  return OUTPUT_CELL.setValues(arrayData);
}

// PRODUCE ARRAY WITH KPIS
function produceArray(data) {
  let kpiArray = [];
  fieldData.forEach(function(item) {
      let fieldDataRoute = data.loadingExperience.metrics[item].category;
      kpiArray.push(fieldDataRoute);
  })
  lighthouseMetrics.forEach(function(item) {
      let lighthouseRoute = data.lighthouseResult.audits[item].displayValue;
      kpiArray.push(lighthouseRoute);
  })
  return kpiArray;
}

// CALL TO API
async function getPageSpeedInfo(strategy, element) {
  let pageSpeedUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=' + element + '&key=' + API_STRING + '&strategy=' + strategy;
  console.log(pageSpeedUrl);
  let response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(pageSpeedUrl);
  let data = await response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Comment: What I tried already was to call a function that passed each url as parameter, but it was giving me a time error because it took too long to return the value, so I made it different.

Comment: look at UrlFetchApp.fetchAll() maybe it can help you https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728